# ES6: How to Add a Static Class Property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In ES5 you can define a `Bar` class as a static property of a `Foo` class, like so:

```
var Foo = function() {};
Foo.Bar = function() {};
```

However, when I try to do something equivalent in ES6, like:

```
class Foo {
    static class Bar {};
};
```

or:

```
class Foo {
    static Bar class {};
};
```

Babel gives me an error.  Is there any way to define an static class property of a class in ES6, or do I just have to use ES6 syntax, ie.:

```
class Foo{}
class Bar{}
Foo.Bar = Bar;
```

Comment: Just saying, in ES6 you'd usually want to put them in different modules (or use a module with named exports) anyway; instead of "abusing" classes as namespaces.

Comment: For most classes I 100% agree.  But when you have a simple class like `class Foo { constructor(foo, bar) {this.foo = foo; this.bar = bar}}`, creating an entire module/file (and then having to import it back in to the original file/module), all for five or six lines of code, just doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean by named exports, you can have multiple small classes in one module and export them directly without nesting them (or building an object)

Comment: Ah, so you're suggesting something like this (in AMD): `define('Foo', function() { return class Foo { constructor(foo, bar) {this.foo = foo; this.bar = bar}}}); RealClass.Foo = require('Foo')`?  Just doing `RealClass.Foo = class Foo ...` still seems better to me (although what I'd really like is `static class Foo ...`).  Either way though, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: No, I mean an ES6 module. `export default class Foo { … } export class Bar { … } …`. You can then `import Foo, {Bar, …} from 'module';`

Comment: You can simply do the same thing you do in ES5 btw.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling, but I was really hoping there was some way of doing it "entirely in ES6".  As my fourth code block shows, using the ES5 approach is certainly an option, but having to define part of a class outside its `class` declaration just feels ... so 2014 ;)